# Export the particular variable of function to another file

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I have a query, that is how I can send "userURL" variable from below file(imageController.js) to another file(contactController.js). and one thing I want to send only "userURL" variable not the whole function "resize". I tried a lot to solve this issue by using "module.exports" but the problem I got is that "module.exports" sending the whole function "resize" not the "userURL" variable. now in second file "contactController.js" where i have mentioned {userURL} in console.log but it's printing only "your result undefined". I just want to export userURL from first file imageController.js to second file "contactController.js".

```
imageController.js


exports.resize = async (req, res, next) => {
 if(!req.file){
   next()
   return
 }

  const extension = req.file.mimetype.split('/')[1]
  req.body.userFile = `${uuid.v4()}.${extension}`
  const photo = await jimp.read(req.file.buffer)
                await photo.resize(500, jimp.AUTO)
                await photo.write(`./public/uploads/${req.body.userFile}`)
  const userimg = photo; 




  console.log(`./public/uploads/${req.body.userFile}`)

  cloudinary.config({
    cloud_name: 'katal',
    api_key: process.env.API_KEY,
    api_secret: process.env.API_SECRET
    }); 

  cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(`./public/uploads/${req.body.userFile}`,{ 
  transformation: { width:100, height:100}}, function(error, result) { 
  console.log('please show result\t' +JSON.stringify(result))

    const userURL ='vikivivki'



    res.send(result.secure_url)
    console.log(result.secure_url)
})
}
```

```
contactController.js

const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Contact = mongoose.model('Contact')
const moment = require('moment-timezone') 
const {userURL} = require('./imageController')


exports.contactForm = (req, res) => {
  res.render('contact')
} 

exports.usermessage = async(req, res) => {

      req.body.name =  req.body.name 
      req.body.email = req.body.email 
      req.body.message = req.body.message 
      const ind = moment.tz(Date.now(), "Asia/Calcutta")

      const newContact = new Contact(req.body)
      await newContact.save() 

      console.log('your result',userURL)


      let showResult1 = JSON.stringify(newContact)
      let showResult = JSON.parse(showResult1)
      res.send(showResult.message)

    }
```

Comment: exports.userURL ='vikivivki'

Comment: and how do i import only this variable in another file @joyBlanks

Comment: const {userURL} = require('./imageController.js')

Comment: got it working? let me know u need more help?

Comment: it's working but it's  printing undefined

Comment: you could update your question to show what you are trying to do for both the files

Comment: now I have mentioned the  second file

Comment: you are not exporting userURL thats why

Comment: Then how can i achieve this

Comment: exports.userURL ='vikivivki' in your first file

Comment: I did it, whatever you said but the console.log is printing "your result undefined"

Comment: check your post it doesnt say that you are exporting userURL

Comment: I didn't get that what you are saying,

Comment: in your question you are writing `const userURL ='vikivivki'` but not `exports.userURL ='vikivivki' ` in imageController.js

Comment: Hey dev, after your first comment, i immediately apply your concept exports.userURL = "vikivivki" but i got only this result "your result undefined"

Comment: did you update the question. I dont know if you did or not or where you placed? can you update the question please??

Comment: Just tell me one thing, did you ever used exports inside exports

Comment: exports are a top level thing

Comment: buddy your file imageController.js only exports resize and not userURL so you will never get userURL in contactController.js

Answer (score 0):

You need to export items you need access to

```
exports.userURL ='vikivivki'; //exporting here along with rezise as well
```

---

**file imageController.js**

```
//imageController.js

exports.userURL ='vikivivki'; //exporting here along with rezise as well

exports.resize = async (req, res, next) => {
 if(!req.file){
   next()
   return
 }

  const extension = req.file.mimetype.split('/')[1]
  req.body.userFile = `${uuid.v4()}.${extension}`
  const photo = await jimp.read(req.file.buffer)
                await photo.resize(500, jimp.AUTO)
                await photo.write(`./public/uploads/${req.body.userFile}`)
  const userimg = photo; 




  console.log(`./public/uploads/${req.body.userFile}`)

  cloudinary.config({
    cloud_name: 'katal',
    api_key: process.env.API_KEY,
    api_secret: process.env.API_SECRET
    }); 

  cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(`./public/uploads/${req.body.userFile}`,{ 
  transformation: { width:100, height:100}}, function(error, result) { 
  console.log('please show result\t' +JSON.stringify(result))

    const userURL ='vikivivki'



    res.send(result.secure_url)
    console.log(result.secure_url)
})
}
```

In your **contactController.js**

```
//contactController.js

const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Contact = mongoose.model('Contact')
const moment = require('moment-timezone') 
const {userURL} = require('./imageController'); // Please have a check on location if they are in the same directory


exports.contactForm = (req, res) => {
  res.render('contact')
} 

exports.usermessage = async(req, res) => {

      req.body.name =  req.body.name 
      req.body.email = req.body.email 
      req.body.message = req.body.message 
      const ind = moment.tz(Date.now(), "Asia/Calcutta")

      const newContact = new Contact(req.body)
      await newContact.save() 

      console.log('your result',userURL)


      let showResult1 = JSON.stringify(newContact)
      let showResult = JSON.parse(showResult1)
      res.send(showResult.message)

    }
```